# Gin-JWT Dynamically set token Timeout based on user

Tags: go, jwt, go-gin

Using Gin-JWT within my Go project I'm having difficulty dynamically setting the token timeout based upon which user logs in via the LoginHandler.  e.g. user A requires a 10-minute timeout while user B requires a 60-minute timeout.  Based upon the user passed to the LoginHandler I need to do a lookup and set the token Timeout.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: please add the relevant code you're having problems with into your question

Comment: @blackgreen Code:  Utilizing the Gin-Jwt library as is [link](https://github.com/appleboy/gin-jwt) I would like to set the token timeout dynamically.